# WCF REST service returns 404 on DefaultAppPool but is ok in 4.0 AppPool (IIS 7)

Tags: wcf, iis, rest

All I change is to go to advanced settings and change the application pool. it works fine when 4.0 is selected and returns 404 when Defaul is.
any help appreciated.

Comment: Is your service implementation done in .NET 4? If so, it should probably be hosted under a .net 4 application pool.